# how to fetch facebook feeds for phonegap 2.9.0 in ios

Tags: ios, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need some help in fetching facebook feeds in phone gap demo project. I am using this [Styling RSS feeds using jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142454/styling-rss-feeds-using-jquery-mobile) .but am confusion for this which index.html will be use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
        <title>feed</title>
        <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("hii")


          $(document).ready(function(){

              $.get("http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=360453900718092&format=atom10", function (data) {
              $(data).find("entry").each(function () { // or "item" or whatever suits your feed
                  var el = $(this);

                  console.log("------------------------");
                  console.log("title      : " + el.find("title").text());
                  console.log("content     : " + el.find("content").text());

              });
            });
          });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```